# input keyboard type prevent html5 cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I would like to create a **HTML input box for 4 digit number**, with following restrictions

1. Even is the user tries to press other than numbers, it should not appear on screen
2. If more than 4 numbers pressed, 5th number should not appear on screen

How to achieve this in **HTML5 hybrid Cordova app while running in mobile device**

I tried

```
<input type="number" maxlength="4" size="4" max="999"/>
```

But in the **google chrome mobile device preview, it allows** any number of characters to be pressed

Is this a default behaviour of webkit?

should we always to post submit validation and throw message?

Comment: So meaning you just using developer tool of Chrome ? Have you tried to install the mobile to Android and iOS to test it ?

Comment: in android and IOS the same thing is happening